# Visio VBA - How can I distribute shapes with a known, fixed distance

Tags: arrays, vba, shapes, visio

I'd like to place all currently selected shapes into an array.  I'd then like to sort that array so I can find either the top most or left most shape in the array.  I'd then like to use that shape as my starting point, and then from there align the other shapes a fixed, known distance apart.  I've tried to place the shapes into an array like so:

```
Dim numShapes As Integer, i As Integer
Dim arrShapes As Visio.Selection

numShapes = Visio.ActiveWindow.Selection.Count
For i = 1 To numShapes
    arrShapes(i) = Visio.ActiveWindow.Selection(i)
Next i
```

I have tried to create the array with no type specification, specifying as variant, and as in this example as selection.  I don't know if I can put them into a list of some kind either?  Obviously I can't get to the point of sorting the array and then distributing my shapes until I can get the array to populate.  I'm placing a break point in the code and I have the "Locals" window open and I can see that the array is not being populated.

Update:

Why does this work,

```
Dim Sel As Visio.Selection
Dim Shp As Visio.Shape

Set Sel = Visio.ActiveWindow.Selection

For Each Shp in Sel
    Debug.Print Shp.Name
Next
```

And this does not?

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim Shp As Visio.Shape

For i = 1 To Visio.ActiveWindow.Selection.Count
    Set Shp = Visio.ActiveWindow.Selection(i)
    Debug.Print Shp.Name
Next i
```

Regards,
Scott

Comment: Simply iterate the shapes and store the left/top most in a local variable (compare the local shape against the shape from the iteration and replace it if the distance is inferior).

Comment: Can't I place the shapes into an array that can be sorted or a collection/list that will use the 'Sort' method?  I've updated my original question to illustrate further.

Comment: Which Sort method are you referring? As far as I'm aware, VBA doesn't have any sort method, which mean that you'll have to implement one.

Comment: *And this does not?* At my side you code works ! You can find shape in top and left side, but how you define next shape in row / column - by ID or shape's current position ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a couple of problems in your code - fixing only one would not have got you any further in understanding if you had actually fixed anything.

- Your `arrShapes` is declared as a general object - the Selection
  Object is one of those objects that is the Jack of all trades, and
  master of none.
- You didn't "Set" when assigning to the array.

I don't have Visio on this machine, so cannot directly test the code below. I am also assuming that all items selected are shapes (usually a safe assumption in Visio).

```
Dim numShapes As Integer, i As Integer
Dim arrShapes() As Shape ' Set this up as an array of shape

If Visio.ActiveWindow.Selection.Count > 0 then ' don't want to cause a problem by setting the array to 0!
    ReDim arrShapes(Visio.ActiveWindow.Selection.Count)
    numShapes = Visio.ActiveWindow.Selection.Count ' while not really necessary it does help explain the code.
    For i = 1 To numShapes
' must Set as we want the reference to the shape, not the default value of the shape.
        Set arrShapes(i) = Visio.ActiveWindow.Selection(i) 
    Next i
Else
    MsgBox "No shapes selected. Nothing done." ' soft fail
End If
```

Comment: Ok I'll try that later this afternoon if I have time.  I want to say that I have done it that way previously and it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I couldn't wait until later, this has been driving me nuts too long.  And of course, something small but very important.  My issue was when I declared the array.  I was missing the parenthesis!  So I was writing "Dim arrShapes As Visio.Shape" when it should be as you have it "Dim arrShapes() As Visio.Shape" ... thanks!